# Annotation @SequenceGenerator and compilation error

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, annotations

I'm .Net programmer but this time I'm working on Java project and I'm encountering some difficulties.
This java project isn't mine, it was developed by other developer and it uses Hibernate.

When I run the Ant builder I receive this error:

```
9: error: annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
@SequenceGenerator( name="companynameSequence" , sequenceName="COMPANYNAME_SEQUENCE" , allocationSize=1 )
^
```

This annotation is in a file called package-info.java. The content of this file is just these few lines of code:

```
@SequenceGenerator( name="companynameSequence" , sequenceName="COMPANYNAME_SEQUENCE" , allocationSize=1 )
package com.companyname.application.model;

import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.jasypt.hibernate.type.EncryptedStringType;
```

If I remove that annotation the project compiles successfully but I have have a runtime error:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: companynameSequence
```

I'm using Eclipse Juno and JRE 1.7

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to write something like this :

```
//different annotations
class className{
        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "COMPANYNAME_SEQUENCE", name = "companynameSequence")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="companynameSequence")
        @Column(name="ID", nullable=false, unique=true)
        private int id;
//other fields and methods
}
```

or this :

```
//different annotations
class className{
        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "COMPANYNAME_SEQUENCE", name = "companynameSequence")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="companynameSequence")
        @Column(name="ID", nullable=false, unique=true)
        public int getId(){};
//other fields and methods
}
```

this is only example and field names may differ from mine.

and read [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id) post about identifiers and generators

Comment: Thank you, but I haven't any "class" in the package-info.java file. There are only the "package" declaration and some import.

Comment: @user2208393 you stack trace tells that it can't find such sequence. Check your full stack trace and I think you find class where you use this sequence and add `@SequenceGenerator` annotation there

Answer (score 0):

Annotations should not affect run-time behavior.  Therefore, I would suggest commenting the annotation out and fixing the bug.  I can't explain, however, the intent of the annotation or why it would throw an error.

Comment: Unfortunally, if I comment the annotation out I receive this exception: 
`Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown Id.generator: companynameSequence`

Comment: @user2208393 Sorry, I can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

i am just running into this issue when migrating from 1.6 to 1.8. The problem here was that @javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator only targets @Target({ TYPE, METHOD, FIELD }), but not the packages. It was a bug until java 1.7 that annotations were not being handled properly. I dont know what the fix is, but I am looking for it.